# Kafka Streams: topic.compression.type not a known config

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Adding the compression configuration in Kafka Streams, similarly as in this [link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-173%3A+Add+prefix+to+StreamsConfig+to+enable+setting+default+internal+topic+configs):

```
properties.put(StreamsConfig.topicPrefix(TopicConfig.COMPRESSION_TYPE_CONFIG), "snappy");
```

but I see the following WARN messages in the log:

```
[2018-11-19 23:52:10,158] WARN The configuration 'topic.compression.type' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig)
[2018-11-19 23:52:10,158] WARN The configuration 'topic.compression.type' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig)
[2018-11-19 23:52:10,194] WARN The configuration 'topic.compression.type' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig)
[2018-11-19 23:52:10,194] WARN The configuration 'topic.compression.type' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig)
[2018-11-19 23:52:10,209] WARN The configuration 'topic.compression.type' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig)
[2018-11-19 23:52:10,209] WARN The configuration 'topic.compression.type' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig)
[2018-11-19 23:52:10,221] WARN The configuration 'topic.compression.type' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig)
[2018-11-19 23:52:10,221] WARN The configuration 'topic.compression.type' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig)
```

Is this setting not honored? Is it not well expressed?

Comment: Finally. Have been looking for hours now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ignore those warnings. The "problem" is, that the topic config parameter is copied into the configs of the internally used clients and they don't know the parameter name and thus WARN about it. However, those configs must be set on the clients, because the clients will "forward" those configs to other parts in the code base that know how to use them.

It's a little unfortunate and a known issue (but not easy to address). There is JIRA for this issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6793